# How to get command value from file or variable in Linux

Tags: linux, input, command

I need to take the command value from file and execute the command,
in my scenario I am rinning this commands ON Terminal

`uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].encryption=psk
uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].key="your_password"
uci commit wireless
wifi`

but i need to pass the value of key i.e "your_password" dynamically i.e from file or from variable where I can store the value taken from python code.
so please tell me how can I pass this value dynamically and execute this commands successfully.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm). You can use io redirection or pipes

Comment: can you be more specific i want value of key from the file testpasswd how can i redirect it to above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use shell variable expansion, like this:

```
password='MYPASSWORD'
uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].key="$password"
```

The important thing here is the dollar sign in `$password`: which signals the shell that what you want is not the string `password` itself, but the *value* the *variable* `password` (defined before) points to.

If you want to read `password`'s value from a file instead of defining it in inline, two approaches are available.

**First approach**
Create a *configuration file* (e.g. `myscript.conf`) and `source` it.  E.g., `myscript.conf` will contain

```
password='MYPASSWORD`
```

and `myscript` will contain

```
source myscript.conf
uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].encryption=psk
uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].key="$password"
uci commit wireless
wifi
```

Be aware that this approach might have security flaws (everything you write into `myscript.conf` gets actually executed in the shell).

**Second approach**
Create a *password* file and just read its content.  E.g., the password file will look like this

```
MYPASSWORD
```

I.e., it will contain just the password.  On the other hand, `myscript` will be

```
password=$(cat password_file)
uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].encryption=psk
uci set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].key="$password"
uci commit wireless
wifi
```

Here we read the content of `password_file` by using `cat` and storing it into the variable `password`.

Comment: thanks Roberto,can I get the value of password from file instead of assigning directly ?

Comment: I just expanded my answer. :)

Comment: If the answer has been useful can you please flag it as the accepted answer?  Thank you!